# Can't make mongoose expires/ttl to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Cache, cache;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

Cache = mongoose.model('Cache', mongoose.Schema({
  value: {},
  createdAt: {type: Date, expires: 3600}
}));

cache = new Cache({
  createdAt: new Date(),
  value: {foo: 'bar'}
});
cache.save(function(err, obj) {
  console.log(err, obj);
  process.exit();
});
```

I'm trying to make the cache get removed after certain time. I waited for more than 3 minutes and the document I inserted did not get deleted at all. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 6):

A preferred way to do this:

```
var cacheSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    value: {},
    createdAt: Date
});

cacheSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 });

mongoose.model( "Schema", cacheSchema );
```

So the [**index**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index) gets defined to deploy when the connection is made and is given the proper creation options.

Probably best practice to separate `Schema` and `model` instance definitions. It's generally handy if you wish to reference that schema somewhere else.

Also see the MongoDB documentation on [**TTL index**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-certain-number-of-seconds) creation.

But also, date math: 60 seconds X 60 minutes = 3600

Answer (score 1):

Run this command `db.yourdb.getIndexes()` in your mongo shell and see what indexes have been created. Check here for more information [Mongoose expires property not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525010/mongoose-expires-property-not-working-properly)